# How to send request and response to different channels after response is received

Tags: spring-integration

Let's say I receive CustomerRequest object into my input channel(Channel 1). 
Now I have to make a webservice call which returns me list of bankaccount objects. 
I have to sum up balance for each account and set that onto CustomerRequest Object. 
Now I need to send the CustomerRequest object to another channel (Channel 2)and list of bankaccount objects to another channel(Channel 3)

I am not sure how to proceed after making the webservice call

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<si:chain id="dataChain" input-channel="channel 1"  output-channel="Channel 2" >
<si:header-enricher >
    <si:header name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
</si:header-enricher>   


<si-http:outbound-gateway id="Gateway1" 
                   url="http://$webservice{host}"                                               
                   http-method="POST" 
                   rest-template="restTemplate"
                   expected-response-type="com.xxx.response.Response1">
</si-http:outbound-gateway>     


</si:chain>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Content Enricher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#content-enricher) (`<enricher/>`). The downstream flow from the enricher should invoke the web service and return the summation.

The enricher would look something like...

```
<enricher input-channel="channel1" output-channel="channel2"
        request-channel="toWsPlusSummationFlow">
     <property name="balance" expression="payload" />
</enricher>
```

This assumes there's a setter `setBalance()` on your `CustomerRequest` and the enricher flow returns the balance as the payload.

The enriched message is then sent to `channel2`.

EDIT:

To update multiple properties on the payload; have the flow return a rich object and just add more properties...

```
<enricher input-channel="channel1" output-channel="channel2"
        request-channel="toWsPlusSummationFlow">
     <property name="balance" expression="payload.calculatedBalance" />
     <property name="accounts" expression="payload.accounts" />
</enricher>
```

This assumes the inbound payload has `setBalance(...)` and `setAccounts(...)` methods and the result of the enrichment flow has a payload with `getCalculatedBalance()` and `getAccounts()`.

The name is an expression that resolves to a setter, the expression is an expression evaluated against the reply from the downstream flow.

Or if you don't want the data in the payload, you can carry it in the headers, using a `<header/>` element.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The enriched message only has the balance i,e original request with total balance.                   But I also want to send List of bank accounts received from the webservice to another channel.   How can we achieve this ?

Comment: If the downstream flow returns a rich object (POJO); you can add multiple `<property/>` elements. I'll update the answer.